# AVAudioPlayer and AVCapture* not working at the same time?

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer, avcapturesession

I try to create an App that records a video and plays back a sound at the same time; both using the AV-Classes (`AVAudioPlayer` & `AVCaptureSession`). Unfortunately I always get an error, when starting recording (music is already playing), saying "An unknown error occurred (-12780)".

Does anyone know this effect? Can't I use two AV-Classes at the same time?